# try except in a while loop - python

Tags: python, while-loop, try-except

Before explaining my question I share my code so it it easier to start directly from there.

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import os

while True:
    try:
        img_name = input('Enter the image file name: ')
        img = plt.imread(os.path.join(work_dir, 'new_images_from_web\\', img_name + '.jpg'))
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print('Entered image name does not exist.')
        img_name = input('Please enter another image file name: ')
        img = plt.imread(os.path.join(work_dir, 'new_images_from_web\\', img_name + '.jpg'))
```

I would like the user to input the name of an image file, and whenever the file does not exist in the directory I want the user to input another file name instead of receiving an error message like the following:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
```

In fact, with the code above, after the second mistaken input I receive an error message with exception `FileNotFoundError`, whereas I would like the loop to go on until an existing file name is given as input. What am I doing wrong in the `while` loop or in the rest of the code?

Comment: So the loop works the first time through?

Comment: @SuperStew I don't think it's the loop, but the first time it works it is for the `try: except:` part

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a `exception` happens outside of `try: except:` it will crash your program. By asking a new input after the `except:` you are outside the capturing-"context": resulting in your program crashing.

Fix :

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import os

while True:
    try:
        img_name = input('Enter the image file name: ')
        img = plt.imread(os.path.join(work_dir, 'new_images_from_web\\', img_name + '.jpg'))
        if img is None:
            print("Problem loading image")
        else:
            break  
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print('Entered image name does not exist.')

# or check img here if you allow a None image to "break" from above
if img:
    # do smth with img if not None
```

It is important to also check/handle img being `None` because `imread()` can return a `None` if problems occure with loading the image (file exists  / but corrupted... or a .txt)

Answer (score 0):

**This helps!**

```
while Ture:
    try:
        img_name = input('Enter the image file name: ')
        img = plt.imread(os.path.join(work_dir, 'new_images_from_web\\', img_name + '.jpg'))
        if not img:
            print("Err")
        else:
            break
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print('Entered image name does not exist.')
    else:
        break
```